# ENTER to TAB redirect - problem with <h:selectOneMenu>

Tags: jquery, jsf

I've redirected ENTER key to TAB key using by this working jquery method:

```
   $('*').live("keydown", function(e) {  
     if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 9) {
       var inputs = $(this).parents("form").eq(0).find(".input");
       var idx = inputs.index(this);
       inputs[idx + 1].select();
       return false;
     }
   });
```

Problem is, I'm able (pressing ENTER) to jump between h:inputText styleClass="input" components only. 
If I want to jump to h:selectOneMenu styleClass="input" next to h:inputText, it submits the form.

How should I change the code to jumping over input and selectonemenu components?

Could you help me?

UPDATE - Working solution:

```
$('*').live("keydown", function(e) 
{    
  var inputs = $(this).parents("form").eq(0).find(".input:visible:enabled"); 
  var idx = inputs.index(this);     // order of components on a form

  // ENTER IS PRESSED
  if (e.keyCode == 13) 
  { // load all enabled, visible and "input" class components from a "form"
    inputs[idx + 1].focus();    // for enter key - allows step to selectOneMenu
    inputs[idx + 1].select();   // and text selection in a field
    //e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }
  // TAB IS PRESSED
  if (e.keyCode == 9) 
  { 
  inputs[idx + 1].select();
  return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: @Naor: Just a small example of code....

Comment: That's not HTML. That's JSF. jQuery does not see/understand JSF. jQuery only sees/understands HTML. JSF generates HTML. Please open the page in browser, rightclick it and choose *View Source*. **That** is HTML. Copy the relevant parts of it which is to be traversed by jQuery.

Comment: Aha:) updated, two inputs and two selects, and after them is submit button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, instead of return false, do:

```
$('*').live("keydown", function(e) {  
     if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 9) {
       var inputs = $(this).parents("form").eq(0).find(".input");
       var idx = inputs.index(this);
       inputs[idx + 1].select();
       e.stopPropagation();
       return false;
     }
   });

$('*').live("keyup", function(e) {  
     if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 9) {
       e.stopPropagation();
       return false;
     }
   });
```

You can also return false after the e.stopPropagation().

**SOLUTION:**

```
$('*').live("keydown", function(e) 
{    
  var inputs = $(this).parents("form").eq(0).find(".input:visible:enabled"); 
  var idx = inputs.index(this);     // order of components on a form

  // ENTER IS PRESSED
  if (e.keyCode == 13) 
  { // load all enabled, visible and "input" class components from a "form"
    inputs[idx + 1].focus();    // for enter key - allows step to selectOneMenu
    inputs[idx + 1].select();   // and text selection in a field
    //e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }
  // TAB IS PRESSED
  if (e.keyCode == 9) 
  { 
  inputs[idx + 1].select();
  return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but it submits a form a step before :)

Comment: Thanks, but it's still the same. Tab key is jumping correctly, but ENTER key isn't... It's weird, both keys should behave the same.

Comment: I've edited your post. Adding new focus causes that ENTER is able to step to select button, so it's could be the solution for me. The is still one issues. ENTER sometimes doesn't step to submit button at the end of jumping form. And that TAB button can't use FOCUS and SELECT together.

Comment: @gaffcz: Sorry but I don't understand what you wrote.

Comment: :-)) It is quite clear that you do not understand, because my attempt to edit your post failed. But that's okay. For completeness, I add my solution updating my original question

Comment: @gaffcz: Ok, If my answers were help you - I appriciate credits.

Comment: Solved. Solution in question.

Comment: @gaffcz: Thanks, I added the solution to here.